# Why won't my button icon change with my click function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript. Why my button won't change from sun to moon color and other works fine, just won't change the icon.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

menu.onclick = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('fa-xmark');
  navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};

let themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button');

themeButton.onclick = () => {
  themeButton.classList.toggle('fa-moon');

  if (themeButton.classList.contains('fa-moon')) {
    document.body.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="nav-right">
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-sun" id="theme-button"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What button?, there are no buttons in your snippet.

Comment: There's an error in the console. Does it appear in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is toggling the class, the icon is not switching because you have two classes `fa-sun` and `fa-moon` which are fighting over the same CSS properties. The order/specificity of the rules must make it so `fa-sun` wins. While in your other one the class you add wins.

You should not rely on the order of the classes in the stylesheet so you should just toggle both classes.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

menu.onclick = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('fa-xmark');
  menu.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
  // navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};

let themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button');

themeButton.onclick = () => {
  themeButton.classList.toggle('fa-moon');
  themeButton.classList.toggle('fa-sun');

  if (themeButton.classList.contains('fa-moon')) {
    document.body.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="nav-right">
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-sun" id="theme-button"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding/removing the `fa-moon` class on click. But you also need to remove/add the `fa-sun` class at the same time. If both class names are present, the class with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) will be used.

```
 themeButton.onclick = () => {
  //This will remove `fa-moon` class if it's already there, add if not.
  themeButton.classList.toggle('fa-moon');
  //You need to do the same for `fa-sun` class. Otherwise, the class never gets removed
  themeButton.classList.toggle('fa-sun');

  if (themeButton.classList.contains('fa-moon')) {
    document.body.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just toggle CSS classes on the `body` element** (like `.is-darkMode` or `.is-menuOpen`).
Change your Fa-icons using the appropriate icon's HEX code in the `::before` pseudo:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);

const elBody = el("body");

const toggleDarkMode = () => elBody.classList.toggle("is-darkMode");
const toggleMenuOpen = () => elBody.classList.toggle("is-menuOpen");

el("#theme-btn").addEventListener("click", toggleDarkMode);
el("#menu-icon").addEventListener("click", toggleMenuOpen);
```

```css
/* DEFAULT STYLES (LIGHT MODE) */
body { background: #eee; transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s; }
#menu-nav { display: none; }

/* DARK MODE STYLES: */
.is-darkMode { background: #444; color: #fff; }
.is-darkMode #theme-btn::before { content: "\f186"; } /* Moon icon */

/* MENU OPEN STYLES: */
.is-menuOpen #menu-nav { display: block; }
.is-menuOpen #menu-icon::before { content: "\f00d"; } /* × icon */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="nav-right">
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-sun" id="theme-btn"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i></div>
</div>

<div id="menu-nav">MENU GOES HERE</div>
```